# Is the existence of substructures satisfying a theory absolute?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory

Given a first-order structure $\mathfrak{A}$ and a first-order theory $T$ one can ask if

$$
\varphi(\mathfrak{A}, T) :=  ``\text{there is a substructure } \mathfrak{B} \text{ of } \mathfrak{A} \text{ such that } \mathfrak{B} \models T \text{''}
$$

holds. I am interested in whether $\varphi$ is absolute between inner and outer models. More formally, let $\mathfrak{A}$, $T$, $\mathbf{V}$, $\mathbf{W}$ be such that

1. $\mathbf{V}, \mathbf{W} \models \mathsf{ZFC}$,
2. $\mathfrak{A}$ is a first-order structure and $T$ a first-order theory in $\mathbf{V}$,
3. $\mathbf{V}$ is an inner model of $\mathbf{W}$, and
4. $\mathbf{V} \models \neg \varphi(\mathfrak{A}, T)$.

Must it be the case that $\mathbf{W} \models \neg\varphi(\mathfrak{A}, T)$?

Comment: This might depend on the cardinality of $\mathfrak{A}$. If everything is countable, Shoenfield absoluteness will apply, but I don't know what will happen otherwise.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Assuming $T$ is countable** (in $V$), the answer is yes.

By downward Lowenheim-Skolem applied to $\mathfrak{B}$, $\varphi(\mathfrak{A},T)$ is equivalent to "$\mathfrak{A}$ has a *countable* substructure satisfying $T$." This lets us interpret $\varphi(\mathfrak{A},T)$ as asking about the ill-foundedness of a certain tree $S$; intuitively, a height-$n$ node on $S$ consists of $(i)$ a choice of the first $n$ elements of a substructure of $\mathfrak{A}$ which will satisfy $T$ and $(ii)$ some data telling us how that structure will satisfy $T$. By Mostowski absoluteness, $S$ is ill-founded in $W$ iff $S$ is ill-founded in $V$.

Countability of $T$ got used twice in the above argument; most obviously when we applied downward Lowenheim-Skolem at the start, but also in the breezed-through bulletpoint $(ii)$. If $T$ is uncountable, both these steps break down.

---

**What if $T$ is uncountable in $V$?**

*EDIT: Below I construct a counterexample where $W$ and $V$ have different cardinals. [Joel's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/453887/8133) shows that with more care we can avoid this, and additionally that it's the uncountability of the language as opposed to any of the structures involved that is crucial.*

Consider the language $\{c_i:i\in\omega\}\cup\{d_i: i\in\omega_1^V\}\cup\{E\}$ where the $c$s and $d$s are constants and $E$ is a ternary relation symbol, and let $\mathfrak{A}$ be the two-sorted structure in $V$ consisting of $(i)$ a "point" for each $c_i$ and $d_j$ and $(ii)$ a "line" $l_{i,j}$ for each pair $i\in\omega,j\in\omega_1^V$ with $E^\mathfrak{A}=\{(c_i,d_j,l_{i,j}): i\in\omega,j\in\omega_1^V\}.$ Basically, we're looking at $K_{\omega,\omega_1}$ with edges being given by objects, not just relations. Note that any substructure contains all the $c_i$s and $d_j$s.

Now let $T$ be the theory saying that the "lines" provide a bijection between the $c$s and $d$s. This is realized in a substructure of $\mathfrak{A}$ after forcing with $Col(\omega,\omega_1^V)$ over $V$, but isn't realized in $V$ itself.

Comment: If $\mathfrak{B}$ is a substructure of $\mathfrak{A}$ with base set $B$, then $E^{\mathfrak{B}} = E^{\mathfrak{A}} \cap B$, no? How does the collapse force a bijection between the $c_i$s and $d_j$s in some substructure of $\mathfrak{A}$?

Comment: @Zoorado The point is that the edges are not just relation instances - they're also elements of the structure themselves. So a substructure of $\mathfrak{A}$ amounts to a *choice of edges*. In particular, given $f:\omega\rightarrow\omega_1^V$, we get the substructure generated by $\{l_{i,f(i)}: i\in\omega\}$. (That said, I did make a typo now corrected - $E$ is ternary, not binary.)

Answer (score 8):

In the general case with uncountable languages, the answer is no.

Let $A$ be a Suslin tree in $V$, considered as a partial order structure in language $\leq$, equipped also with predicates $U_\alpha$ for every countable ordinal $\alpha$, holding of the nodes of $A$ on level $\alpha$.

Let $T$ be the theory asserting that the nodes are linearly ordered and have a node on every level $\alpha$. Any submodel of $A$ realizing this theory would have to consist of a cofinal branch through $A$.

Consequently, there is no submodel of $A$ satisfying this theory in $V$, since $A$ is a Suslin tree and therefore has no cofinal branches in $V$.

But if we force with the Suslin tree, we arrive at a forcing extension $W=V[G]$ in which $A$ does have a branch. So in the forcing extension $W$, there is a submodel of $A$ satisfying the theory $T$.

By taking $A$ merely as an Aronzajn tree, we see thereby that every model of ZFC has an extension violating the stated absoluteness. The Suslin tree example shows, however, that even if we know that cardinals are the same between $V$ and $W$, it is not enough to get absoluteness.

**An example with a countable model.** Let me give an example with a countable model (but uncountable language). Consider the usual binary infinite tree $\newcommand\P{\mathbb{P}}\P=2^{<\omega}$, as an order relation, growing downwards in the forcing style. Let us add a predicate symbol $\hat D$ for each subset $D\subseteq\P$. Let $T$ be the theory asserting that the nodes are linearly ordered, and that they contain an element of $\hat D$, whenever $D$ happens to be a dense subset of $\P$. In short, the theory asserts that the submodel is a $V$-generic path through $\P$.

Since there is no $V$-generic path in $V$, there is no substructure of $\P$ realizing this theory in $V$. But if we force to add a generic path, then in the forcing extension $W=V[G]$ there is a submodel of this theory.

Since this forcing is the forcing to add a Cohen real, which is ccc, this example shows how to violate absoluteness even while $V$ and $W$ are very close. Every model of ZFC $V$ violates absoluteness with the forcing extension $W=V[c]$ obtained by adding a Cohen real, for the countable structure $\P$ I described.

The same idea works with any forcing notion $\P$. Consequently, every nontrivial forcing extension $V\subseteq V[G]$ provides an instance of nonabsoluteness. In $V[G]$, there is a filter $G\subset\P$ that meets every dense subset of $\P$, and this is expressible by a suitable first-order theory, but in $V$, there is no such generic filter, and hence no submodel of that theory.

Comment: Re: needing a Suslin tree in $V$, do you know if every $V$ has a cardinal-preserving extension $W$ which violates this absoluteness property?

Comment: Good question. Both of our arguments in the general case involve collapsing an uncountable cardinal. Let me think about it....

Comment: I've realized how to do it, and furthermore with a countable structure.

Comment: Lovely! I was actually just thinking (vaguely motivated by [this old MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3250951/does-any-uncountable-complete-theory-have-exactly-two-countable-models)) about whether a countable structure in an uncountable language could do the job here.